# Consolidate data from closed workbooks adodb approach

Tags: excel, vba

I have found a code and modified to suit my files. The code is supposed to loop through closed workbooks (7 files) and import specific columns (myHeading) to ThisWorkbook

```
Sub Consolidate()
    Dim a, ws As Worksheet, myDir As String, myHeading As String, sFile As String, cn As Object, rs As Object
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder"
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        If .Show Then myDir = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
    If myDir = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    a = Array("Accrued Date", "Description", "Amount Accrued (LC)", "Product", "Account Description", "Product Charge Code", "Country")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With ws
            .Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(a) + 1).Value = a
            With .Cells(1).CurrentRegion
                myHeading = "`" & Join(.Parent.Evaluate(.Rows(1).Address & "&"""""), "`, `") & "`"
                .Offset(1).ClearContents
            End With
        End With
        sFile = Dir(myDir & "*.xlsx")
        Do While sFile <> ""
            Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            With cn
                .Provider = "Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0"
                .Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"
                .Open myDir & sFile
            End With
            rs.Open "Select " & myHeading & " From `MyReport$`;", cn
            ws.Range("A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
            rs.Close: cn.Close
            Set cn = Nothing: Set rs = Nothing
            sFile = Dir
        Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code takes too long time (about 5 minutes) although the files are only 7 and I have used ADODB approach which I know is more faster than opening the excel files directly.
Any ideas how to make it faster and what may obstacles the code and make it slow?

Comment: How big are the excel files?

Comment: You could try Power Query

Comment: The files size about 5 - 6 MB. I don't have experience at Power Query and I prefer using VBA.

Comment: I think you can reuse the connection and record set objects with out  destroying and recreating them each time through the loop.  Might help a bit

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried that but it seems no difference in time. The code still takes time to get the data. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this (I couldn't test the code):

**EDIT:**

Commands can only be used if connected to an actual Database.

```vb
Sub Consolidate()
    Dim a, ws As Worksheet, myDir As String, myHeading As String, sFile As String, cn As Object, rs As Object
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder"
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        If .Show Then myDir = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
    If myDir = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    a = Array("Accrued Date", "Description", "Amount Accrued (LC)", "Product", "Account Description", "Product Charge Code", "Country")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With ws
            .Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(a) + 1).Value = a
            With .Cells(1).CurrentRegion
                myHeading = "`" & Join(.Parent.Evaluate(.Rows(1).Address & "&"""""), "`, `") & "`"
                .Offset(1).ClearContents
            End With
        End With
        sFile = Dir(myDir & "*.xlsx")
        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        With cn
            .Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Persist Security Info=False;"
        End With
        Do While sFile <> ""
            Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            rs.Open = "Select " & myHeading & " From [Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = Yes;Database=" & myDir & sFile & "].[" & "MyReport$];"
            ws.Range("A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
            Set rs = Nothing
            sFile = Dir
        Loop
        cn.Close: Set cn = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I encountered `Requested operation requires an OLE DB Session object, which is not supported by the current provider` at  this line `.ActiveConnection = cn`

Comment: @YasserKhalil I updated the code. Can you try again? The `With cn` part is changed

Comment: Thank you. Now error `Authentication Failed ` at this line `.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Persist Security Info=False;"`

Comment: @YasserKhalil I updated the code. I guess `Commands` can only be used, when an actual database is connected...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience. I got `Authentication failed` at this line `.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Persist Security Info=False;"`